# 200 votes is maybe too high a cut-off for tags

Tags: feature-request, superuser, serverfault, meta, generalist-badge

Kudos to the 6 people on SU and 8 people on SF for getting the Generalist badge: that's a real achievement.

Meanwhile, here on MSO, no-one has generalist.  The reason is that only 22 tags have at least 200 questions in them, although there are over 11 000 questions here.  Even the `serverfault` tag is below that threshold.

**Request** — Halve the threshold for number of questions per tag to 100, so that these tags are less deeply heroic outside of SO.

Any issues with that?

Comment: 3 downvotes: not a popular qn!  What's the problem - should this have been a discussion question before posting a feature request?

Comment: Regarding downvotes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-are-the-rules-different-on-meta

Comment: it's good to put a feature request directly, no need for a discussion before. As you can see in the above link, downvotes on meta, especially on feature requests, are simply that some people disagree with the request, that's all. It's not about you or the way you wrote the question.

Comment: @waiwai, @Gnoupi: Yes, thanks, it's all clear now.  I guess I should be using my downvote stick a bit more around here, as well!

Answer (score 4):

Or we can wait for the other sites to have the same amount of questions as SO.

Generalist won't be awarded a lot at first, and it's ok. In my opinion, this badge makes sense only with a mature list of tags. Reducing the threshold would only go against the "maturity" idea.

Comment: *Personal note: if one day SU has as much success as SO currently has, with recent questions disappearing after 15 minutes, and still manages to not become a mess like Y! answers, I think I will request a "Impressive" badge for moderators and active voting users :-]*

Comment: +1 maturity: This is a good point.  This actually doesn't apply to SF/SU, because the first 40 tags actually are over the 200 vote threshold for those sites.  I was actually thinking, besides MSO,  of sites outside SOFU, like MO, which has only 16 tags above the threshold, but has a pretty mature culture.  Given that part of the intent is that SOFU should be a trailblazer for the Stack Exchange sites, this is maybe a consideration.